# How Can I access Database From One server

Tags: php, jquery, .net, json

i have website abc runing on one server online , and i have library inventry system 'xyz'  in php runing on another server which have static ip like 203.215.166.77, my question is how can i access the database from abc to xyz in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MYSQLI**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('10.0.0.1', 'user', 'password', 'db', 'port ( imporant for external connection ');
```

**MYSQL**

```
$link = mysql_connect('10.0.0.1:PORT', 'user', 'password');
```

You need to open the port from your database for the other server. This you can do in the firewall ( default port is 3306 )

Answer (score 1):

Well, the way I see it, you have 2 options..

Option 1: Direct database connection from server 1 to server 2. You will need to allow server 1's IP address on server 2's SQL database. (See S. Visser's answer for code)

Option 2: Create a REST API that you can cURL to from server 1 to server 2.

Comment: hmm if i go with option 1 you can give me example how can i fix it or any idea

Comment: Well, I've only used cPanel for my PHP hosting, and in there I could set up a list of allowed IP's to remotely access the DB. Once you've done that, you set up a normal DB connection, but instead of connecting to localhost, you connect to the static IP.